# UIView height constraint animation, which has anchor connection with other views

Tags: xcode, animation, constraints, swift4

Xcode swift 4

I have some views that are added dynamically in code one below another.
Each new view top anchor is connected to previous view bottom anchor.
And each view have a button that make view to expand/collapse with animation. Here is button code :

```
    let fullHeight : CGFloat = 240
    let smallHeight : CGFloat = 44

    let currentHeigth  = rootView.frame.size.height //I use this to get current height and understand expanded view or not

    let heighCons = rootView.constraints.filter //I use this to deactivate current height Anchor constraint
    {
        $0.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.height
    }
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(heighCons)
    rootView.layoutIfNeeded()

    if currentHeigth == smallHeight
    {
        rootView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: fullHeight).isActive = true
        rootView.setNeedsLayout()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5)
        {
            rootView.layoutIfNeeded() //animation itself
        }

    }
    else
    {
        rootView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: smallHeight).isActive = true
        rootView.setNeedsLayout()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5)
        {
            rootView.layoutIfNeeded() //animation itself
        }
    }
```

This all works perfectly but i have a problem : view that below current expanding view changes it y position immediately with no animation. Its just jumping to previous view bottom anchor, that would be active after animation finish.

So my question is :

1) what is the right way to make height constraint animation, when views are connected to each other by bottom/top animation?

2) my goal is just to make a view that would expand/collapse on button click, maybe i should do it another way?

Answer (score 2):

[image]
[image]

**Here's an approach using Visiblity Gone Extension**

```
extension UIView {
func visiblity(gone: Bool, dimension: CGFloat = 0.0, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute = .height) -> Void {
    if let constraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == attribute}.first) {
        constraint.constant = gone ? 0.0 : dimension
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.isHidden = gone
    }
 }
}
```

**Usage**

```
expanview.visiblity(gone: true,dimension: 0)
```

**Example**

```
@IBOutlet weak var msgLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var expanview: UIView!
@IBAction func toggleCollapisbleView(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected{
        sender.isSelected = false
        expanview.visiblity(gone: false,dimension: 128)
        sender.setTitle("Collapse",for: .normal)
    }
    else{
        sender.isSelected = true
        expanview.visiblity(gone: true,dimension: 0)
        sender.setTitle("Expand",for: .normal)
        msgLabel.text = "Visiblity gone"
    }

}
```

Comment: tabassum, thanks for answer, but it is not exactly what i need. Your code works, but using it with animating view expand works the same way as my solution.(View that need to collapse or expand changes it height with animation, but other views just jump to the new position without animation). To understand what i mean, just remove "self.layoutIfNeeded()" extension UIView and put it after calling visibility method expanview.visiblity(gone: true,dimension: 0)                                 rootView.setNeedsLayout() UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5)  { rootView.layoutIfNeeded() }

Comment: tabassum no it is not done)your code does not work right with animation. i need something like this but for Xcode https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout

Comment: @Bios90 https://i.gyazo.com/b39131440dd2a32b58ccdf9897ac5b02.gif?_ga=2.183845798.1200529799.1533795303-1557991276.1533795303 can u plz check this link

Comment: tabassum on your GIFs all works exactly as i need, but with my views its work another way. My views are added dynamically without storyboard, with "translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints = false", and top anchor of every new view is bottom anchor of previous, maybe it is the reason.

Comment: so u can use tableview for adding dynamic views.